# Take arguments in strings in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a program that allows users to type in strings and the program will return a string based on the string the user typed. I want to be able to take arguments in the strings (eg. helloworld(arg1,arg2,arg3)).

What I currently have is a textbox that will allow users to type in a command, my program can currently respond depending what command is typed. What I want is to be able to also repond depending on what arguments have been given in the format above.

Example:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then assume that user types: `function(aa,bb,cc);`

I want to get a list of parameters (aa, bb and cc in this case).

How would I be able to parse this out?

Comment: Are you asking how to accept distinct string arguments in a console (command-line) program? Can you provide an example of how you'd like it to work?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I think you might be asking how to [tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) an input string?

Comment: I've made my own command line interface using the FastColoredTextBox control, I want users to be able to type string(arg1,arg2,arg3) and my program return the arguments one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string input = "function(aa, bb, cc);";

    string pattern = @"\((?<str>.+)\)";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match m = regex.Match(input);

    if(m.Success)
    {
        string str = m.Groups["str"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        string[] args = str.Split(new char[] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    } else {
        // unable to parse
    }
```

And it becomes little bit more complicated if arguments can contain commas.

Comment: This works great! Is there any way to just apply this to the words inside the brackets?

Comment: Gimme 5 minutes, I'll update the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. The arguments won't contain commas

Comment: Check this out, I've updated the answer. It works for me ( http://dotnetfiddle.net/M2Meys )

Answer (score 4):

Try the `params` keyword.

```
void HelloWorld( params string[] args )
{
    foreach(var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

`params` allows for a variable number of same-type arguments to be passed in. For more information on `params` [see the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

And after you build your program to make the helloworld.exe you can pass command line parameters from the console.

Eg:
`C:\> HelloWorld.exe arg1 arg2 arg3`

^^ To do this you need to pass the command line arguments from `Main` as such:

```
public static void Main( params string[] args )
{
    HelloWorld( args );
}
```